# What is the keywords of major contributor of a project?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing my resume.

I want to write that I was not the sole responser of the project, I did get suggestion from the director, but I am the major contributor of the mechanical and electrical engineering parts of the half million project.

How should I rephase ?

Comment: Saying that you are the major contributor/benefactor of the project and that you received suggestions from your director seems ok to me.

Comment: The word *benefactor* is **mainly used** for some financial help which does not seem an OP's concern.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think it sounds like you're in charge of the whole "mechanical and electrical engineering parts" of the project, under the supervision of your director. If that's what it was, you could write that. You should just be specific with what you did, don't try to overstate it or understate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible alternative:

> I had primary responsibility for all mechanical and electrical engineering aspects of this $500,000 project.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways and versions of this phrase to be conveyed. Nevertheless, here is the one I'd have gone for -

> I was the major contributor to a [USD?] half-million project for the inputs of mechanical and electrical engineering.

Comment: What does the "for the inputs of" part mean?